# How to group within categories

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to eliminate duplicated data within ID across multiple categories.  Is it possible to eliminate duplicates for each category in one query? If I had one category that would be simple as adding a group by ID.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_PROFILES(CATEGORY,ID,REGION_ID)
    SELECT D.category_id, C.ID
    FROM MATCH_DATA C JOIN
         CATEGORY_TABLE D
         ON c.EXTERNAL_ID = d.device_id;
```

Comment: Can you please let us know what is structure of tables and where you can have duplicates?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: How is this going to work? You are inserting into three columns, but you are SELECTing only two values? (This is in addition to, not instead of, the other responders' questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using distinct

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_PROFILES(CATEGORY,ID,REGION_ID)
SELECT distinct D.category_id, C.ID
FROM MATCH_DATA C JOIN
     CATEGORY_TABLE D
     ON c.EXTERNAL_ID = d.device_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you were looking for? Distinct?

```
Insert INTO TABLE_PROFILES(CATEGORY,ID) SELECT distinct D.category_id, C.ID FROM MATCH_DATA C JOIN CATEGORY_TABLE D ON c.EXTERNAL_ID = d.device_id;
```